# electron-builder.ps1 cannot be loaded because running

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

i trying to convert a website to desktop app with js electron i found this problem while i build my exe app:

```
electron-builder : File C:\Users\firas lweti\AppData\Roaming\npm\electron-builder.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ electron-builder --win
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

[image]

i need to convert my website to desktop app

Comment: Try opening powershell as admin, and running: `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted`

Answer (score 2):

that's a powershell configuration that deny the scripts execution.
you need to set it for allow it
open a terminal and type:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

it will ask for confirmation, select option [A] to confirm

[image]